# Erasing value in one variable if value in another variable do not have a match in a list in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table with two fields:

```
dd <- data.frame(measure = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), class = c(1,11,2,22,3,33), stringsAsFactors = F)
dd
  measure class
1       a     1
2       a    11
3       b     2
4       b    22
5       c     3
6       c    33
```

For each `measure`, a `class` is associated.  However, not all `class` can be associated to each `measure` value.  Actually, the only values allowed per measure are available in a `list`:

```
ls <- list(a=c(1,10), b=c(2,20,200), c=c(3,30,90))
ls
$`a`
[1]  1 10

$b
[1]   2  20 200

$c
[1]  3 30 90
```

I need to erase (replace by NA), the measure where the class as no match in the list.  I succeeded in base R:

```
good_match <- mapply(function(xx, yy) any(xx %in% yy), ls[dd$measure], dd$class)
dd$measure[!good_match] <- NA
dd
  measure class
1       a     1
2    <NA>    11
3       b     2
4    <NA>    22
5       c     3
6    <NA>    33
```

However, I would like to do it in `dplyr`, probably with `mutate`, so I can pipe 
it and make it fit better in my script.  I've tried:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>%  mutate(measure = ifelse(any(class %in% ls[[measure]]), measure, NA))
Error in ls[[measure]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

I have a feeling it fails because of a problem of vectorization of some sort but I'm stuck.  Do you know of a another, more elegant way, of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a join after converting the named `list` to a tibble/data.frame

```
library(tidyverse)
enframe(ls,  value = 'class') %>%
   unnest %>%
   right_join(dd, by = 'class') %>%
   transmute(measure = name, class)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  measure class
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 a           1
#2 <NA>       11
#3 b           2
#4 <NA>       22
#5 c           3
#6 <NA>       33
```

---

A `base R` option would be using `stack` (instead of `enframe`) and `merge`.

NOTE: `ls` is name of a function.  It is better not to name object identifiers with function names